# How do I check if a bot reacted to a message with on_raw_reaction_add (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I currently have an event function for 'on_raw_reaction_add.' How do I check if a *bot* reacted to the message instead of a normal user?

Comment: If it is only the add event, you can just check if `payload.member.bot` is true. Note that this will not work on the `on_raw_reaction_remove` event

Comment: As of what moinierer3000 is saying also try showing us your code with the `on_raw_reation_add` so we can see the mistake you made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
if payload.member.bot:
    return
```

Thanks!